# Unity Android build keeps failing when at the Gradle phase no matter what I do

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, compiler-errors, compilation

For some reason, this app that months ago compiled just fine is failing at the gradle phase. The full error log in this;

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
 C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.9f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\gradle-6.0.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

 stderr[
 C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:10: error: class MyService is public, should be declared in a file named MyService.java
 public class MyService extends Service {
        ^
 C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
                                  ^
 C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
     @Nullable
      ^
   symbol:   class Nullable
   location: class MyService
 3 errors

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
 > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 1m 24s
 ]
 stdout[
 > Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:checkReleaseManifest
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:processReleaseManifest
 > Task :preReleaseBuild
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
 > Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
 > Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
 > Task :checkReleaseManifest
 > Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
 > Task :prepareLintJar
 > Task :generateReleaseSources
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResValues
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseResources
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:packageReleaseResources
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseRFile
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:prepareLintJar
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:generateReleaseSources
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:javaPreCompileRelease
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
 > Task :GooglePlayGamesManifest.plugin:bundleLibCompileRelease
 > Task :javaPreCompileRelease
 > Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
 > Task :generateReleaseResValues
 > Task :generateReleaseResources
 > Task :mergeReleaseResources
 > Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
 > Task :processReleaseManifest
 > Task :processReleaseResources

 > Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
 Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
 See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
 22 actionable tasks: 22 executed
 ]
 exit code: 1
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
 UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0)
 UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)
```

What can I try to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try changing to Internal build instead of Gradle build.
2) You environment changed. The environment includes:

- you installed another copy of Android SDK
- you installed new version of Unity editor and opened this project

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code that are listed in Gradle.

> The `stderr []` block will tell you what is wrong and why Gradle failed to sync or build.

#### Error `error: class MyService is public, should be declared in a file named MyService.java`

This means you have a file with a different name (in this case `notificationService.java`) that `MyService.java`. Rename `notificationService.java` to **MyService.java**

> Public Java classes must be in a file named after them

#### Error `error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import android.support.annotation.Nullable;`

Means you have not added `annotations` in your `mainTemplate.gradle` or `Dependencies.xml` of Jar resolver.

**Add the library then**

`app/build.gradle`

```
// dependencies
com.android.support:support-annotations:+
```

#### Error `error: cannot find symbol @Nullable ^ symbol: class Nullable location: class MyService`

This is related to the previous error. Means you need `Annotations support library` to build this class.

Errors are achieved from this part:

```
stderr[
C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:10: error:class MyService is public, should be declared in a file named MyService.java public class MyService extends Service { ^ 
C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:7: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist import android.support.annotation.Nullable; ^ 
C:\Users\Buccura\Documents\Unity\NemexiaMobile\MOBILE\Code - Copy (2)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\java\notificationService.java:13: error: cannot find symbol @Nullable ^ symbol: class Nullable location: class MyService 3 errors
```

Comment: This is what my maintemplater.gradle looks like. Where exactly would I put the annotations:+ into?  

// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

buildscript {
    repositories {**ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

Comment: **BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {**ARTIFACTORYREPOSITORY**
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each {
    ext {
        it.setProperty("android.useAndroidX", true)
        it.setProperty("android.enableJetifier", true)
    }
}

Comment: ([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = "file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**"
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository") // Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

Comment: There's a lot more but that's the first bit. If it'll help I can post the rest.